# Define a choice of prerequisites in a pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For example, lets say I have a compiler that can build `foo` files from either `bar` or `baz` sources.

The rules for this might look like:

```
%.foo: %.bar
    # commands to
    # invoke compiler

%.foo: %.baz
    # commands to
    # invoke compiler
```

However, this could start getting a bit long and redundant as the number of input types and recipe commands increase. Is there any syntax available to compress this into a single rule?

```
%.foo: $(oneof %.bar %.baz)
    # commands to
    # invoke compiler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose at the beginning is right: Makefiles should be clear and concise regarding building rules.

In the other hand you may take a look at [Canned Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html) to try to avoid repeating the same recipes once and again:

```
define MAKE_FOO =
#You may use automatic variables such as $^ or $@.
mv $< $@    #In this example just a file renaming.
endef

%.foo: %.bar
    $(MAKE_FOO)

%.foo: %.baz
    $(MAKE_FOO)
```

The *canned recipe* `MAKE_FOO` will expand to whatever recipes you write inside the `define` statement as if they were copied manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustration for the concrete problem of making an `.o` file
from either a `.c` file or a `.cpp` file with a combined pattern rule.
An executable is also built to aid the illustration.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: test

%.o: %.c %.cpp
    gcc -c $?

test: main.o hw.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f test *.o
```

where we have:

**hw.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hw(void)
{
    puts("Hello from C");
}
```

**hw.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void hw()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C++" << std::endl;
}
```

and:

**main.cpp**

```
extern "C" void hw(void);

int main(void)
{
    hw();
    return 0;
}
```

Make from clean and run:

```
$ make clean && make && ./test
rm -f test *.o
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
gcc -c hw.c hw.cpp
g++ -o test main.o hw.o
Hello from C++
```

Both `hw.c` and `hw.cpp` were compiled per the pattern rule.

*Each one of them was compiled to the same object file*, `hw.o`, *with the second, C++
compilation overwriting the C compilation*. So the C++ object file was linked,
simply because it was the last to be built. Be clear about what you expect to 
happen when the combined rule is triggered by *multiple prerequisites*.

Now let's update `hw.c` and repeat:

```
$ touch hw.c
$ make && ./test
gcc -c hw.c
g++ -o test main.o hw.o
Hello from C
```

This time, `hw.o` was compiled only from `hw.c`, and linked.

Update `hw.cpp` and repeat:

```
$ touch hw.cpp
make && ./test
gcc -c hw.cpp
g++ -o test main.o hw.o
Hello from C++
```

Once again, the `hw.o` from C++ was linked.

The key element of the combined pattern rule is [`$?`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), which
means *all the prerequisites that are newer than the target*

Comment: I'm not sure what the source code adds to the answer. More importantly, what happens if only one of the sources exists?

Comment: The source code just provides a working example and explains why you see what you see. If only one the `.c` or `.cpp` exists then that's the one that's compiled.

Comment: OK, but I'd find the answer a lot more readable if it were shorter.